# Android - like UICollectionView

Tags: android, gridview, uicollectionview, grid-layout, staggered-gridview

I want to create a ui that like below :

[UICollectionView Sample](https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=uicollectionview&rlz=1C5CHFA_enTR721TR722&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjs8_H4cvbAhWGPxQKHY88CCQQ_AUICigB&biw=1216&bih=613#imgrc=FJgDqgM2BdcQ0M:)

There are some view and layout for this behaviour on android.

**GridView**: Fixed column number. It is useless for upper case.

**StaggeredGridLayoutManager**: Constructor requires span count. It is useless for upper case.

**GridLayoutManager**: It don't need a fixed column count.

```
GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 6);

    layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            switch (position % 5) {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                    return 3;
                case 2:
                case 3:
                case 4:
                    return 2;
            }
            throw new IllegalStateException("internal error");
        }
    });
```

But I have to give a column number for each row. How can I do this task on android like ios?

Comment: Android does not provide anything like you are looking for, perhaps there is a library somewhere but nothing native

Answer (score 0):

try [FlexboxLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) library from github.